# Polynomial producing only primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

The polynomial:
$$a_n x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_{1}x+a_{0}$$
Coefficients a<sub>i</sub> are natural numbers, the claim is once you substitute the positive integers 1,2,3,... for $x$ the values of the polynomial are distinct primes (the polynomial only produces primes). Prove that if the constant coefficient of the polynomial $a_{0} = 0$ then the claim is false.

If anyone could help me i'd really appreciate it i'm very lost.

Comment: I assume that you include zero in the naturals? Is there any context - if this is a homework question are there results from the course that could be useful? If it isn't a homework question, why do you think the claim is false when $a_0 = 0$?

Comment: The earlier version of the question only mentioned $1,2,3$ (no $\dots$). For that version, the result does not hold.

Comment: If the $a_i$ are all 1 and there are an odd number of them, and $$a_0=1$ then , evaluating at $1$ will not give you a prime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call this polynomial p(x). Since the constant term is 0, we can write p(x) = x * p1(x), where p1(x) is another polynomial. so p(4) for example must be divisible by 4 and cannot be prime (since 4 itself is not prime).

EDIT: I have a feeling you meant that the values are distinct primes if we substitute distinct primes for x, like x = 2, 3, 5, 7, etc. because that is the interesting case. Let me prove it for that version too.

In that case, p1(x) must be 1 for all prime x. In other words, p1(x) - 1 = 0 has infinitely many roots (all prime numbers are roots). This cannot happen since a polynomial of finite degree can only have finitely many roots.

EDIT 2: Actually, this can happen if p1 is identically 1. But I guess p(x) = x is probably not what we are looking for here.